# batch find file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

If I am iterating over each file using :

```
@echo off

FOR %%f IN (*\*.\**) DO (
    echo %%f
)
```

how could I print the extension of each file? I tried assigning %%f to a temporary variable, and then using the code : `echo "%t:~-3%"` to print but with no success.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The FOR command has several built-in switches that allow you to modify file names. Try the following:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.*) do echo "%%~xi"
```

For further details, use `help for` to get a complete list of the modifiers - there are quite a few!

Answer (score 7):

This works, although it's not blindingly fast:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.*) do call :procfile %%f
goto :eof

:procfile
    set fname=%1
    set ename=
:loop1
    if "%fname%"=="" (
        set ename=
        goto :exit1
    )
    if not "%fname:~-1%"=="." (
        set ename=%fname:~-1%%ename%
        set fname=%fname:~0,-1%
        goto :loop1
    )
:exit1
    echo.%ename%
    goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3):

[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138819#138847)'s answer is definitely the easiest for what you want. But I wanted to add:

Don't `set` a variable inside the `()`'s of a `for` and expect to use it right away, unless you have previously issued

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

and you are using `!` instead of % to wrap the variable name. For instance,

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (

   set t=%%f
   echo !t:~-3!

)
```

Check out

```
set /?
```

for more info.

The other alternative is to call a subroutine to do the `set`, like [Pax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138819#138913) shows.